# WPF label at slider thumb

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

I need to customize wpf slider thumb - i could do it any shape or color but I have no idea how to place a label in the thumb (for displaying current slider value). May be some one do something like this?

Comment: Have a look at:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163497.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The BEST way I have found is to attach tooltip for the thumb.